# Django Forms : disable field if booleanfield is checked

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Here is the definition of my form:

```
class WorkflowForm(forms.Form):   
    new_user = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    user = ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

I would like to disable the *user* ModelChoiceField if the *new_user* field is checked.

So is it possible to define in this class a dependency for a field to another, like in my case a modelchoicefield depend of a booleanfield checked or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a quick simple one,

```
<p>label for="id_new_user">New user:</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="new_user" id="id_new_user" 
        onclick="javascript:toggleDiv('user_choice');" checked/></p> 

<p id="user_choice" style="display:none">        
    <label for="id_user">User:</label> 
    <select name="user" id="id_user">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="1">sam</option>
        <option value="2">usertest</option>
    </select>
```

**forms.py**

```
class WorkflowForm(forms.Form):   
    new_user = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
    user = ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkflowForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.all()
        self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'display:none'
        self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['id'] = 'user_choice'
        self.fields['new_user'].widget.attrs['onclick'] = "javascript:toggleDiv('user_choice');"
```

**templates**

```
{{form.as_p}}

<script>
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $("#"+divId).toggle(500);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
the interresting part is onclick="javascript:toggleDiv('user_choice');
But with the Django form library, how can i add this to the tag ? 
Should it be define into the forms.py ? or override something else ?

Comment: haha, my sorry for my english, i m also new in django.
my forms.py is in the first part; at the top of the page.

Comment: class WorkflowForm(forms.Form):   
    new_user = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    user = ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)

Comment: yes, the user selected in the ModelChoiceField should be a user instance. for sure if the check box is checked i will validate the form by myself by ignoring the user instance selected, and redirect to the user creation page. but it's better to disable this selectbox if the checkbox is checked :)

Comment: I don't know if the attributes of modelchoicefield is correct. You can search it on how to add attributes in django forms

Comment: Thank you very much Catherine, i try to implement

Comment: Sorry for the noob i am, but in your answer; forms.py
you forgot a "," after the initial=True in the new_user and after that i have a "}" expected by the ide ... on this line:
widget=forms.TextInput(attrs='onclick':'javascript:toggleDiv('user_choice');'})

Comment: Ok i don't understand all you put in the init with this famous super()
I guess you override the constructor, so in my views.py i have a line where there is form = WorkflowForm()
and when the template is call, i have this error: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: It looks good, i removed the argument user. Even if the checkbox is checked or not the modelchoiceField is not showed... 
but thank you a lot

Comment: i remove the line with self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'display:none'. the selectbox is showed but nothing if the checkbox is checked or unchecked. 
I think i will avoid insert javascript for the moment and create a button to redirect the user in case of new user. 
In a short future i guess i will need to show or not a part of a form depending of a checkbox :( héhé

Answer (score 0):

As your form is not a ModelForm, I assume what you mean is client side: if the user checks the *new user* checkbox, the *user* field becomes disabled.

You can't do that on the side of Python, as it's all happening in the browser, and not on the server. You need to use javascript. Example using jQuery:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#check').click(function() {
            var disable = $(this).is(':checked');
            $('#choice').attr('disabled', disable);
        });
    });
```

Good luck.