# disabling/enabling a field in Django form depending on a value of another field in the same form

Tags: python, django, field, modelform

Asking a beginner's question.
I have a ModelForm object with a quite large number of fields. I want some of these fields to assume to be editable or not editable, based on a value of some other field (in the same form):
For example:

```
split_words = forms.BooleanField()
split_words_min_length = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1,max_value=140)
```

I would like `split_words_min_length` field to be disabled (or not displayed), if `split_words` is set to `False` (unchecked).
What would be a clean way how to achieve this?

Comment: This is likely something you need to do with JavaScript: Django renders a HTML form, but once the response is constructed, then it can no longer change the content.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I get the idea, now I will look how to do the job in Javascript.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261286/django-forms-disable-field-if-booleanfield-is-checked